# Typescript: Is there something that works like a union type, except we can access properties that aren't common to all types of its union?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, properties, union-types

"If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union"

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

I'm looking for a way to use a dynamic variable that can be any of multiple types, and through it, access the properties of one of the types that aren't common to all the other types in the union

[edited example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20INTERFACE0%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name1%20%3A%20TYPE%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name2%20%3A%20%7Bkey%3A%20%22value%22%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TYPE%20%3D%20INTERFACE1%20%7C%20INTERFACE2%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20INTERFACE1%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AND%20%3A%20%5BTYPE%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20INTERFACE2_A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20A%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20INTERFACE2_B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20B%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20INTERFACE2_C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20C%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20INTERFACE2%20%3D%20INTERFACE2_A%20%7C%20INTERFACE2_B%20%7C%20INTERFACE2_C%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20performFunction(interface%3A%20INTERFACE0)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20type%20%3D%20interface.TYPE%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2):

Use a type guard in combination with a union type.

The following `Foo | Bar` union type can be of either type. By also using type guards, we can access the properties `Foo` that are not common to `Bar`.

```
class Foo
{
    public DoFoo = () => document.write("Foo");

    public Shared = () => document.write("FooShared");
}

class Bar
{ 
    public DoBar = () => document.write("Bar");

    public Shared = () => document.write("BarShared");
}

function isFoo(obj: Foo | Bar): obj is Foo { 
    return obj instanceof Foo;
}

let foobar: Foo | Bar = new Foo();

foobar.Shared(); // FooShared

if (isFoo(foobar)) {
    foobar.DoFoo(); // Foo
}
```

We can [paste it here to play with it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

In answer to your comment, if the variable is not instantiated but instead passed into a function, the situation looks like this:

```
function SomeFunction(foobar: Foo | Bar)
{ 
    foobar.Shared(); // FooShared

    if (isFoo(foobar)) {
        foobar.DoFoo(); // Foo
    }   
}
```

Comment: what if the variable is not instantiated, and is instead inputted as a parameter in a function? when i try to access one of its properties inside the function, i'm told that the property must be in all of the types in the union

Comment: The same idea still exists when we pass it into a function @icda. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Could you take a look at my example in my edited post? i'm not sure what's wrong with it (sorry about the large link)

Comment: @icda Well, for one, you are using strings to define properties, which is not the canonical way to define properties in TypeScript.

Comment: @icda Consider starting with the example that I posted in my answer. Then change it one bit a time until it works with your use case.